# Capture domain and url using reg-ex?

Tags: regex

I have a following string -

```
1489713397.743 69 201.3.120.132 TCP_REFRESH_HIT/200 3013 GET http://www.google.com/manta/images/homepage/h_ftr-snapdata.gif pcallahan@google.com DIRECT/www.google.com - ALLOW_WBRS-DefaultGroup-Demo_Clients-NONE-NONE-DefaultRouting <IW_busi,6.5,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,IW_busi,-> - -
```

I want to extract the following capture groups - user, domain and url.

For the above line it should return me the following -

*User =  pcallahan@google.com*

*Domain = http://www.google.com*

*URL = http://www.google.com/manta/images/homepage/h_ftr-snapdata.gif*

Comment: What language you want it?

Comment: `^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using .NET, the following regex should extract the 3 groups you're looking for:

```
(?<url>http://(?<domain>[^/]*)[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*)
```

But this will work only if your data follows the assumptions I have made looking at the sample you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex in javascript. All you need to do it to using group matching:

```js
var str="1489713397.743 69 201.3.120.132 TCP_REFRESH_HIT/200 3013 GET http://www.google.com/manta/images/homepage/h_ftr-snapdata.gif pcallahan@google.com DIRECT/www.google.com - ALLOW_WBRS-DefaultGroup-Demo_Clients-NONE-NONE-DefaultRouting <IW_busi,6.5,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,IW_busi,-> - -";


var rgx= /(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/ig

var match = rgx.exec(str);

if (match){
console.log(match[0]); // the entire url
match[1] && console.log(match[1]); // onyl the domain

}
```

Here is the regex in javascript:

```
(https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/ig
```

Now here is an example: